# Make runnable file from Python code with modules

Tags: python, makefile, runnable

I'm trying to create runnable file using makefile, usage similar to compiling code with gcc etc.

There is no problem mark script as "runnable" using chmod + inserting line #!/usr/bin/python
And then I basicly got what I wanted to have - runnable file able to be run by ./file_name ... BUT the problem I'm trying to solve is splitting project to more files and actually "compile" code making one runnable file including created modules.

I found something like command "python -m compileall" creating .pyc file. But not sure if it's that, what I want to achive, because I cannot mark ".pyc" file with chmod due to "operation denied". Because I creating script on remote server where I got no access to sudo.

Anyone more experienced at this issueses?

I would like to achieve one runnable file with code of all the separated files.

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for [pyinstaller](http://pyinstaller.org).

Comment: shame I cannot install anything on the server, any tips? Is it able to use is without installation?